# ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed. for k Fold validation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, cross-validation

Here is my model

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(units=8000,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=1000,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=500,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=100,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))

# For a binary classification problem
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is my K fold declaration

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, epochs=10)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator,X[0:15500], y[0:15500], cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

I get the below error regarding a layer.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: DeprecationWarning: KerasClassifier is deprecated, use Sci-Keras (https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras) instead. See https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html for help migrating.
  
Baseline: nan% (nan%)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
10 fits failed out of a total of 10.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 236, in fit
    return super(KerasClassifier, self).fit(x, y, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 153, in fit
    **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3095, in _split_out_first_arg
    'The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.')
ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)
```

Trying to figure out what it is, tried many things but still failed. Hope someone could solve it with a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically have your model as a method like below,

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(units=8000,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=1000,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=500,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=100,activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

Next call it

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
results = cross_val_score(estimator,X, y, cv=kfold)
```

This worked for me, I suppose the 'build_fn' param of the KerasClassifier expects a method to be called.